# How to disable phpMyAdmin login page?

Tags: sql, laravel, .htaccess, security, phpmyadmin

I've a problem with my live site.

When I entering this address:

```
www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin
```

appears phpMyAdmin login page.

I don't understand the reason, because on the local version phpMyAdmin isn't displayed.
Is there a way to disable, hide or block the login page?

Thank you!

Comment: Your hosting company has provided phpMyAdmin so you can administer your databases, you should search their documentation or email their support if you want to turn it off.

Comment: Yes @Andrew , you're right.
I supposed, but thought it was my mistake. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is hosting. Solution found.

Thank you!